# rails_xss requires Rails 2.3.8 or later. Please upgrade to enable automatic HTML safety.

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Got this very annoying message everytime I run rake task:

```
rails_xss requires Rails 2.3.8 or later. Please upgrade to enable automatic HTML safety.
```

Have checked, already have `rails_xss` and `Rails 2.3.11` installed, and gem environment is pointing to the right path.

How to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some versions of `rails_xss` compare versions using string comparison, so they stopped working when Rails 2.3.10 came out (since "2.3.10" < "2.3.8"). If you install a more recent version, it should work. It's possible the bug has not been fixed in the gem, but in the worst-case scenario you can get the latest version of the plugin from https://github.com/rails/rails_xss.